# MS SQL Stored Procedure for counting Dynamic table items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I had wrote this below stored procedure and getting incorrect statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Counter]
        @TableName VARCHAR(100)
    AS 
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Counter INT
            DECLARE @SQLQ VARCHAR(200)
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

        --SET @TableName = 'Member';
        SET @SQLQ = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[' + @TableName + ']';
        --Preparing the above sql syntax into a new statement(get_counter).

            --Getting an error here I had googled the prepare statement but don't know why facing this error.
        PREPARE get_counter FROM @SQLQ;
    @Counter = EXEC get_counter; -- here @resutl gets the value of the count.@TableName
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE get_counter; -- removing the statement from the memory.


    END
```

Then I had wrote another one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Counter]
    @TableName VARCHAR(100)
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Counter INT
        DECLARE @SQLQ VARCHAR(200)
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        --SET @TableName = 'Member';
        SET @SQLQ = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[' + @TableName + ']';
        --Preparing the above sql syntax into a new statement(get_counter).


    Execute @SQLQ; -- here @resutl gets the value of the count.@TableName

        --DEALLOCATE PREPARE get_counter; -- removing the statement from the memory.
        Return @Counter;

    END
```

It is running fine but I can't get the result in the Counter , anyone please help me(I know that I haven't assigned any value to the counter but if I do I get error).

After your answer martin I had replace my code with yours now its :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Counter] @SchemaName SYSNAME = 'dbo' , @TableName  SYSNAME

AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @SQLQ NVARCHAR(1000)
      DECLARE @Counter INT;

      SET @SQLQ = 'SELECT @Counter = COUNT(*) FROM ' + 
       Quotename(@SchemaName) + '.' + Quotename(@TableName);

      EXEC sp_executesql
        @SQLQ ,
        N'@Counter INT OUTPUT',
        @Counter = @Counter OUTPUT

      Return   SELECT @Counter
  END
```

Now I had retrieved it .

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[CreateBusinessCode]
    @MemberID                               bigint,
    @len                                        int,
    @RewardAccountID                bigint,
    @ConnectionStatusID         tinyint,
    @Assign                                 smalldatetime

AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @counter INT

    EXEC @counter = dbo.Counter 'dbo','member';

    Select @counter;


    END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `SYSNAME` for object identifiers and `Quotename` rather than concatenating the square brackets yourself.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Counter] @TableName  SYSNAME,
                              @SchemaName SYSNAME = 'dbo'
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @SQLQ NVARCHAR(1000)
      DECLARE @Counter INT;

      SET @SQLQ = 'SELECT @Counter = COUNT(*) FROM ' + 
       Quotename(@SchemaName) + '.' + Quotename(@TableName);

      EXEC sp_executesql
        @SQLQ ,
        N'@Counter INT OUTPUT',
        @Counter = @Counter OUTPUT

         SELECT @Counter
  END
```

Comment: Excellent @Martin Smith. Can you please explain the code from EXEC line?

Comment: I think I got the explanation from this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, if you want to get a result into a variable, you have two choices.

The first is to use cursors.

The second is to do dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = whatever;
declare @cnt int;

declare @cntTable table as (cnt int);

insert into @cntTable
    exec(@sql);

select @cnt = t.cnt
from @cntTable
```

It is cumbersome, but one or the other does work.

Comment: What will happen if try Select statement instead of insert into statement? Can you please explain?

Comment: It will not work.  You can insert the output of an exec statement into a table.  You cannot select from it.  (For a select, SQL Server needs to know the structure of the table when the query is compiled.  It doesn't have that information for an exec statement.)

Answer (score 0):

try this one.It doesnt query the actual table but will provide you the count of rows.This is better way if you have large tables and you need approximate count.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Counter] 
    @TableName VARCHAR(100) 
AS  
begin

declare @objectid int,@counter int
select @objectid = object_id from sys.all_objects where name = @tablename and schema_id=SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
select @counter = sum(rows) from sys.partitions where object_id= @objectid
and index_id in (0,1)
select @counter
end
go
```

Comment: Thank you. It is also helpful.